# My jQuery "showcase" - opacity issue :)

Tags: jquery, css, image, jquery-animate, opacity

I am having a bunch of photos and I'm looking for best way of displaying them at the same place using jQuery.

What do you think of my concept? Is it valid or maybe there are other ways than putting all images on each other and playing with opacity?

Anyways I don't know why this code:

> jQuery('#demo img
>   .'+itemClass).animate({opacity: 1});

Doesn't show a thing. Any helping hand?

http://jsfiddle.net/d4sEW/1/

Comment: I think that jQuery isn't an object ( shouldn't it be `$('#demo img.'...)`?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I´m pretty sure class names can´t start with a number, but even so, if your image has a certain class, you have to use `img.'+itemClass` instead of `img .'+itemClass`; you put a space between the img selector and the class.

Apart from that you will have to remove / fade-out the images that you don´t want to show as otherwise one image can show behind an image you don´t want to show.

Answer (score 2):

Ok this is what I did for it to work:

- Remove a space here: `jQuery('#demo img .'+itemClass)` to `jQuery('#demo img.'+itemClass)`
- I would also recommend you hide the images before showing the desired one (if you select an image, lets say #3, and then select the first image again, it wont be displayed since the 3rd is over it)

Comment: There's no need to change jQuery to $; The code is fine either way.

Comment: I didn't know that, I'm used to see `$`. Besides, the code is smaller; thus, loads faster.

Comment: @JC0C611: Perhaps the OP is not able to use $ to call jQuery functions because of another library.  Also, the question did not involve increasing the performance of the code.  Additionally, the first bullet point implies that the change is necessary to make it work which is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

Right a few problems.

Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/d4sEW/7/

- `.attr('class')` - this is wrong, there is no attribute class, it's `.attr('className')`
- you need to switch the other opacities to 0, otherwise whichever is on top of the stack will show
- if you want that to look right, you will need to either carefully pick which pictures to fade in and out, or fade the lot out prior to fading in, as shown in the demo
- also, you need to close the space between `img` and the class, otherwise it looks for a class as a descendant of the image, not a part of it: `$('img.class')`

Answer (score 1):

You have typo(no space) between img and itemClass.
it should looks like this :

```
jQuery('#navi a').click(function(){
  var itemClass = jQuery(this).attr('class');
  $('#demo img').animate({opacity:0});
  jQuery('#demo img.'+itemClass).animate({opacity: 1});
  //alert(itemClass);
});
```